# Getting the last string of a link

Tags: javascript, jquery, url, slug

I have been searching for a while with no success, I found ways to get the current URL but can't figure out how to get the last string for a specific link.

The Url would be something like

http://www.mywebsite.com/slug/

What I would need to get is the "slug" part out of the link's URL

My current function:

```
$('.filters a').click(function(e){
e.preventDefault();
var slug = '';
alert ( slug );
});
```

Any help will be appreciated :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
$('.filters a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slug = $(this).attr('href').split('/');
    slug = slug[slug.length - 2];
    alert(slug);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="filters">
   <a href="http://www.mywebsite.com/slug/">Slug Link</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try a regex like

```
$('.filters a').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var slug = $(this).attr('href').match(/[^/]*(?=(\/)?$)/)[0];
    alert(slug);
});
```

- `[^/]*` - 0 or more characters other than `/`
- `(?=(\/)?$)` which is followed by  0 or 1 instance `/` and line end